# Using DataTables.net, how do I add data in each column before the ajax call gets made to load it?

Tags: datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables and I would like to pack some data in some of the columns before it sends it to ajax. The dataTables.js has: d.columns.push( { data:       dataProp, ... so I was thinking of trying to store it in data: key, when I analyzed the data that gets sent, I see columns[0][data]: foo.bar  so I was going to try and pack it in there, but how do I do this?

Comment: I think this needs a [mre]: some code and data we can easily copy, paste and run for ourselves, to recreate your problem. (As your question is currently written, I an not sure what it is you want to do, what you have already tried, what happened when you tried it, or what a successful outcome would look like.)